# session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 98

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this error:

```
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 98
Current browser version is 100.0.4896.75
```

I have allready manually downloaded the correct chrome driver and inserted it into the project debug folder. But each time I debug it override the new chrome driver with version 100 and insert back the chrome driver with version 98.

How can i avoid this?

What i need to do, that the chrome driver in the folder stay on version 100 and get not overriden by starting debugging.

Comment: The version of the ChromeDriver you use has to match the version of Chrome installed on the machine. You should acquire it from NuGet, rather than manually fiddle with the contents of your bin/Debug folder. One approach to keep them in sync can be to do something like this MSBuild target that downloads the ChromeDriver version for the version of Chrome installed: https://github.com/martincostello/dotnet-core-selenium-tests/blob/88f8be5cb3d09ab6a9f0d75cd17481031acd2313/seleniumtests/seleniumtests.csproj#L19-L92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 98
Current browser version is 100.0.4896.75
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=100.0*
- But you are using *chromedriver=98.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=98.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/98.0.4758.102/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 98

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=98.0* and the *chrome=100.0.4896.75*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to [ChromeDriver v100.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.60/) level.